# open source blog like wordpress

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, iis, blogs

I need open source blog, something like Wordpress. I have a limit, whichever is the only solution that runs on IIS and uses SQL Server Express. Any solutions for this problem??

Comment: Probably more of a Superuser thread? No idea. But you can run Wordpress on IIS with SQL Server. http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/coolstuff/WordPress-Now-Runs-on-SQL-Server-and-SQL-Azure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [Microsoft Web Platform](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx). In among the dev tools, there's a bunch of free web applications, including a variety of blogs (notably [blogengine.net](http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/BlogEngine.NET.aspx)) and full-fledged CMSes like DotNetNuke.

Update: And as a nod to @birryree's comment, note that the Web Platform *includes* Wordpress! :)